# vCenter Server Appliance Autostart Services Stopped

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

Look at all these automatic start services that are stopped after a reboot.
[image]
And navigating to the vSphere client returns a "no healthy upstream" error.

This appliance is a couple *days* old. Deployed using the tiny preset, it manages 1 host. Trying to start the services just spins forever. I'm temped to just recreate it since there really isn't too much on this thing but I'd still like to know if anyone has an answer as to why this is happening.